# How to pre-install a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a browser, which relies on an extension to work properly. I have not yet published the extension to the store and would prefer to avoid doing so. Is there a way for me to automatically install or pre-install an extension, to allow for easy distribution along with the actual browser?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried the registry method already, but for some reason, the extension still won't appear. I am assuming this is a deprecated feature. Plus the link you have sent only applies for extensions listed in the Google Store

Comment: Maybe https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting then.